# gridview delete and allowpaging issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've searched and am now at a loss as to the cause of my problem.

Here's the short version of my issue.

I have a gridview, a checkbox to toggle paging of the gridview on/off and a sql datasource with select and delete queries. If paging is on, I can click delete for a row in the gridview and it runs and the page refreshes no problem. If I turn paging off for the gridview, the delete query appears to run when I do a direct query against the table in sql server but the page fails to reload. I get the following error:

> Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   value  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   value
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   value]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_SelectedIndex(Int32
>   value) +280
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDeleteCallback(Int32
>   affectedRows, Exception ex) +352
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary oldValues,
>   DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +119
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow
>   row, Int32 rowIndex) +938
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs
>   e, Boolean causesValidation, String
>   validationGroup) +1152
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +190
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +7
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +11    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +172
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4920

Here is the page code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsSQL_ClaimsDetail" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:activeDB_Connection %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblReturnClaimDetail] WHERE [ID] = @ID" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:activeDB_Connection.ProviderName %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID, HeaderID, CustomerSKUData, NikeInvoiceOrSalesOrderNumber, StyleandColorCode, StyleCode, ColorCode, StyleName, WholesaleDolrs, OriginalWholesaleDolrsPerUnit, Units, AccountDiscDolrsPerUnit, TotalNetPriceDolrs, HandlingandProcessing, Negotiated, NegotiatedReason, NegotiatedOptionType, NegotiatedOptionValue, FinalUnitPrice, FinalDolrs, FinalStandardDolrs, UpdateTime, UpdateUser, BatchUser, Approved, Denied, Pending, ClaimDisposition, FinalDecisionDate, ClaimRecordNumber, ASMName, Category, Gender, Other1, Other2, Other3, GBURegion, Division, BudgetManagerName, ClaimsBudgetYear, ClaimsBudgetQuarter, ApprovedDate, ReconciledBy, ReconciledDate, ReconcileOrigionalLineID FROM tblReturnClaimDetail WHERE (HeaderID = @claimID)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lbl_ClaimNumber" Name="claimID" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox_detailPagerToggle" runat="server" Text="View all styles at once" Visible="True" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True" />&nbsp;</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grid_Details" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="dsSQL_ClaimsDetail">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Edit" ShowSelectButton="True">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
            </asp:CommandField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NikeInvoiceOrSalesOrderNumber" HeaderText="Nike Invoice /&lt;br /&gt;Sales Order #"
                HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="NikeInvoiceOrSalesOrderNumber" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StyleCode" HeaderText="Style Code" SortExpression="StyleCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ColorCode" HeaderText="Color Code" SortExpression="ColorCode" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StyleName" HeaderText="Style Name" SortExpression="StyleName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GBURegion" HeaderText="Channel" SortExpression="GBURegion" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginalWholesaleDolrsPerUnit" DataFormatString="{0:c2}"
                HeaderText="WholeSale&lt;br /&gt;$/Unit" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="OriginalWholesaleDolrsPerUnit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Units" HeaderText="Units" SortExpression="Units" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountDiscDolrsPerUnit" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Discount&lt;br /&gt;$/Unit"
                HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="AccountDiscDolrsPerUnit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HandlingandProcessing" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Handling &amp;&lt;br /&gt;Processing"
                HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="HandlingandProcessing" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Negotiated" HeaderText="Negotiated" SortExpression="Negotiated" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NegotiatedReason" HeaderText="Negotiated Reason" SortExpression="NegotiatedReason" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NegotiatedOptionType" HeaderText="Negotiated Type" SortExpression="NegotiatedOptionType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NegotiatedOptionValue" HeaderText="Negotiated Value" SortExpression="NegotiatedOptionValue" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FinalDolrs" DataFormatString="{0:c2}" HeaderText="Final $ for Product"
                HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="FinalDolrs">
                <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Transparent" />
            </asp:CommandField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The only code behind for the 3 objects in question is on the checkbox:

```
Protected Sub chkbox_detailPagerToggle_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkbox_detailPagerToggle.CheckedChanged
    If Me.chkbox_detailPagerToggle.Checked = True Then
        Me.grid_Details.AllowPaging = False
    Else
        Me.grid_Details.AllowPaging = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas to get me looking in the right direction would be wonderful because I am at a loss for where to go next to solve this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if the GridView is confused about the number of rows that are getting deleted, and tries to set the selected index to an invalid value.

Does it only occur when the last row is deleted?

Are there any triggers firing when you do the delete? That can cause the @@RowCount to get messed up. Try adding "SET NOCOUNT OFF" before and "SET NOCOUNT ON" after your delete call.

I am guessing, but perhaps with paging on, the SetSelectedIndex code works slightly differently.

Comment: I didn't even think of checking the trigger. I just checked and nocount fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about using SProcs instead of straight SQL? It'd get pretty messy with those NO COUNTS now.

Comment: I have considered it and am working on transitioning over to stored procedures but I inherited this project and there are currently far bigger issues to address than that at the moment, one being trying to begin normalizing a database made up of flat tables.