# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I am deleting a row from grid view I am getting following error. "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: value ".
The following is the Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value) +1353411
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDeleteCallback(Int32 affectedRows, Exception ex) +368
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +137
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex) +714
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +869
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +123
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +135
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

Please suggest me.

No. I didnt set set any index manually.My code sample as follows:                                                                   
                
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            '>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            ' >

```
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="srcData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GermanyCockpitDB %>"
            SelectCommand="SP_BPGetData" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            OnSelecting="srcBP_Selecting" DeleteCommand="SP_BPDeleteRecord"
            DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnDeleting="srcData_deleting">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Manager" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Period1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Period2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Period3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Period4" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ManagerName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="AName" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource><br /><br />  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gvData.DataSourceID = "srcData";
        gvData.DataBind();
    }

}protected void srcData_deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@ManagerName"].Value = "Sample";
}

protected void srcBP_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@ReportsToManager"].Value = "Sample";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Period1"].Value = "0";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Period2"].Value = "1";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Period3"].Value = "2";
    e.Command.Parameters["@Period4"].Value = "3";
}
```

Comment: suggest you to post code for the delete failing as above

Comment: what is your code behind to do deleting?

Comment: What does the line [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value]
tell you?

Comment: The other 2 parameters Name and AName are DataKeyNames of gridview

Comment: See if this helps you out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534234/gridview-delete-and-allowpaging-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you're trying to set the selectedindex to a wrong index. Do you set it manually somewhere in your delete callback or pageload(prender,...)?

Comment: Then can you show how you're feeding your grid and the what you do in the delete event?

Comment: Why don't you put the datasourceid directly in the markup? moreover you don't need to call databind when using the datasourceid. If the datasourceid is set, the gridview will call databind automatically based on the RequiresDataBinding property.